# Rendering an array of html elements

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, reactjs

I want to render an array of html elements in my component. The reason for storing the data/html in an array is because I want to be able to dynamically load a new element depending on a button-click.
This is how I want to display my array:

```
 <div>
       {this.state.steps}
 </div>
```

This is how I initiate my component and array:

```
  componentDidMount() {
        this.createProcessStep().then(step => {
            this.setState({steps: this.state.steps.concat(step)});
        });
    }
  export function createProcessStep() {
    this.setState({processStepCounter: this.state.processStepCounter += 1});
    return this.addStepToArray().then(d => {
        return this.reallyCreateProcessStep()
    });
  }
 addStepToArray = () => {
        const step = {
          ...Some variables...
        };
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            this.setState({
                stepsData: this.state.stepsData.concat(step)
            }, resolve)
        });
    };
```

"stepsData" is another array that holds data (variables) belonging to each step. "steps" on the other hand, should only hold the html.
This is how one step/element looks like:

```
<div>
 ...Some Content...
 <button label="+" onClick={ () => {
                            this.createProcessStep().then(step => {
                                this.setState({
                                    steps: this.state.steps.concat(step)
                                });
                            })
                        }}/>
 ...other content...
</div>
```

This button within each step is responsible for loading/adding yet another step to the array, which actually works. My component displays each step properly, however react doesn't properly render changes to the element/step, which is
to say that, whenever e.g. I change a value of an input field, react doesn't render those changes. So I can actually click on the "+"-button that will render the new html element but whenever a change to this element occurs,
react simply ignores the phenotype of said change. Keeping in mind that the changeHandlers for those steps/elements still work. I can change inputfields, radioButtons, checkboxes etc. which will do exactly what it's
supposed to, however the "re-rendering" (or whatever it is) doesn't work.
Any ideas of what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: maybe this can help you? https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react

Comment: can you maybe explain how this npm could help? and how it works? does it wrap a component around or whats the benefit?

Comment: Hey you managed to resolve this? If not then:  Your creation & addition works fine, the code for which you've provided, but can you include updation code too? So we can have a look & get a idea about way you are handling it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could certainly beat your approach into working, I would advise that you take more common react approach.

You make your components to correctly display themselves from the state . ie as many steps are in the state, your component will display. Than make your add button add necessary information (information, not formated html) to the state.

Here is an example how to use component N times:

```
const MyRepeatedlyOccuringComponent = (n) => (<p key={n}>There goes Camel {n}</p>)

const App = () => {
 const camels = [1,22,333,4444,55555]
 const caravan = camels.map((n) => MyRepeatedlyOccuringComponent(n))
 return(<div>{caravan}</div>
}
```

Comment: what would you recommend me as a common react approach?

Comment: What I have written in second paragraph. Your state contains infiormation needed to display all the steps. Your Components correctly render that information. Add button, just ads more information to the steps. Or to summarize, it is common to keep in state only information and not formated html, formatting is left to the components.

Comment: You think storing html in State is not Common

Comment: I think it kind of defeats separation of responsibilities between components and state.

Comment: And to clarify some more. While you may have valid reasons to try to store html in state, need to "dynamically load a new element depending on a button-click" is not one of them since this need can be easily satisfied without storing html in state

Comment: and where should I store html If I need the HTML Part N times?

Comment: you do not store it, you have component that renders it, and you use that component N times.

Comment: how can I use the component N times? with .map? or can you possibly give me a minimal example?

Comment: I have added example how to use component N times. Note that I did not use data from the store as it should be in real life situation but from constant to keep example short